# Best way to store lot of data for quick request

Tags: database-design

I do have a **database with millions of rows on a not so fast server**, and I have to get some of these rows every week. The thing is that it's about people, and they are associated to a localisation number, but this number is different according to a distributor.

For exemple let's say we have `Mr.X`
For **distributor A**, `Mr.X` localisation will be `"01"`, but for **distributor B**, it might be `"171"`.

So here is how my database look right now :

```
Table Person : Identifiant, name, ...

Table Distributor-A : Identifiant, localisation, ...

Table Distributor-B : Identifiant, localisation, ...
```

There is and will only be **2 distributor**, so I thought about putting all the information I need every week as `"name"` from table Person also in the tables `Distributor-[]`, so I won't have to make an inner join on the table Person which is really heavy and slows a lot my querys.

But I also know it's usually a bad idea to store the same information at several places in a database. However I'm not used to work with important amont of data and I really need to make it faster, so that's why I need some advice !

Thank you for your time

Comment: Hello, before answering i want to know if i understand your question correctly. Basically you want to request data from database faster and for that you want to store a person's information from table "person" & from both distributors as 1 row so you don't have to use relationships? is that correct? Also can you provide more column names from all 3 tables so i can understand and try to recreate the design accordingly.

Comment: @AmirQureshi Hello, yes it's that. both table distributor are about how a person is seen by the distributor (localisation) and the table Person contain data which are always the same (name, telephone number..)
i sometimes need to pick only people from distributor A or B, so I don't really know what to do there are several possibilities. Maybe add "localisation-distributor-A" and B in the table Person can also be an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyy Gary, pardon me if i didn't understand your question correctly.

So what i got is that you have many persons and each person has localisation numbers different for both distributors.

Lets say , Person named "*John Doe*" has his personal information stored in **Persons** table.

John has relationships with both distributors, so to get the localisation number from both distributors table named **Distributor_A** & **Distributor_B** we need to query both distributor tables, well whats an easy way of doing it?

Let see if this helps you out.

**Persons table design**

```
Columns
-- ---- --------- ----- --- 
Id Name Telephone Email Age Etc...
-- ---- --------- ----- ---
```

We are going to make a new table named "Localisation_numbers".

**Localisation_numbers table design**

```
Columns
-- --------- ---- ----
Id Person_id No_a No_b
-- --------- ---- ----
```

We are going to store localisation numbers in table **Distributor_A** , **Distributor_B** & also in **Localisation_numbers**.

**OR**

You can store localisation numbers only in **Localisation_numbers** table & drop table **Distributor_A** & **Distributor_B**.

You can set No_a & No_b column default value to 0 which would mean that the person does not have relationship with the distributor and if the value is not 0 that means they do have a relationship with distributor.

To pick John Doe's localisation numbers , check the example below.

```
Persons table
-- ---- --------- ----- --- 
Id Name Telephone Email Age
-- ---- --------- ----- ---
12 John 010101010 john@ 39
```

&

```
Localisation_numbers table
-- --------- ---- ----
Id Person_id No_a No_b
-- --------- ---- ----
1  12        348  210
```

Now we need to *search for the row in Localisation_numbers* table which has Person_id same as John's Id in Persons table & then we can pick values of column **No_a** & **No_b**.

Let me know if this helps you and if you understand this.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply !
I didn't even think about erasing distributors table as we are used to work on it, and import new data on it. But if we go further into your idea, could it be a good idea to store No_a and No_b for the localisation table directly into Person table ?

Comment: Yes you can do that too, the new table method was to keep everything clean and simple.